# Android Studio: How to get a Object with a List of Object with Spring-Resttemplate

Tags: java, android, json, spring, resttemplate

I have to admit, that I need some help with something.
I have only 3 weeks experience with Rest, 2 weeks experience with Grails and one week experience with Android Studio, so I hope you won´t be too hard with me.
I get this Json from a grails Server:

```
{"class":"medicserver.Medication",
"id":1,"dateOfPrescription":"2015-09-19T08:12:34Z",
"description":"Meds",
"medicationUnit":[{"class":"medicserver.MedicationUnit","id":1},{"class":"medicserver.MedicationUnit","id":2},{"class":"medicserver.MedicationUnit","id":3}],
"patient":null}
```

You see, the attribute "medicationUnit" is a List of MedicationUnit and this is the only thing my ResponseObject doesn´t have, when it´s created. I simply don´t get it. 
Here is Rest-Code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mapping = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
            mapping.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(mapping);
            Medication medication = restTemplate.getForObject(url , Medication.class);
            return medication;
```

My Classes - plaese ignore the static Type. This is to realise inner Classes :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    static class Medication{

        String description;

        MedicationUnit[] medicationUnit;

        Date dateOfPrescription;


        public Medication(){

        }

        public void setDescription(String description){
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getDescription(){
            return this.description;
        }

        public void setMedicationUnit(MedicationUnit[] medicationUnit){
            this.medicationUnit = medicationUnit;
        }

        public MedicationUnit[] getMedicationUnit(){
            return this.medicationUnit;
        }

        public void setDateOfPrescription(Date dateOfPrescription){
            this.dateOfPrescription = dateOfPrescription;
        }

        public Date getDateOfPrescription(){
            return this.dateOfPrescription;
        }

        public String postAll(){
            String result = this.description + "\n" + String.valueOf(this.dateOfPrescription) + "\n";
            for(MedicationUnit med: this.medicationUnit){
                result = result + med.postAll();
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
```

MedicationUnit:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
static class MedicationUnit {

    String name="Hans";

    Date intakeTime=new Date(0);

    int dosage=3;


    public MedicationUnit(){
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setIntakeTime(Date intakeTime){
        this.intakeTime=intakeTime;
    }

    public Date getIntakeTime(){
        return this.intakeTime;
    }

    public void setDosage(int dosage){
        this.dosage=dosage;
    }

    public int getDosage(){
        return this.dosage;
    }

    private String postAll(){
        String result;
        result = this.name + " " + String.valueOf(this.intakeTime) + " " + String.valueOf(dosage) + "\n";
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: The JSON indicates that the class of the units is `medicserver.MedicationUnit`. But your MedicationUnit class seems to be nested in another class, and its name is thus not `medicserver.MedicationUnit`. Do you use different classes between the client and the server?

Comment: My MedicationUnit, my Medication and my Rest-Function are in the same Activity.
And MedicationUnit works perfectly fine with my Server. I had written an extra API to make sure of it. The only Problem is the List in Medication. I´m sure of it

Comment: You're not answering my question. Do you use the exact same class to generate the JSON on your server and to read it in the client? If not, then do.

Comment: Thanks I will try, I´m not completly in this theme. I thought the needed components are coded in the json. My Teammember wrote that part and it sems to be something like an Mapping-Table. I will ask him a little bit more about that

Comment: Alrighty the mistake is somewhere in the Server. I have to ask my mate about it!
Thank you again JB for taking your time, you saved my day, man! :D